# A silly confusion in the process of finding the transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the transformation matrix for the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{3}^3$ defined as $T(x,y)=(x+2y,z+x,y-z)$, given the basis $\alpha =\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\beta=\{(1,1,0),(0,1,-1),(0,1,0)\}$.

I tried to think the following, we want a matrix that takes $(x,y)$ to $(x+2y,z+x,y-z)$. Then I guess I could do the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x & y 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 A& B &C \\ 
 D& E &F 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 x+2y&x+z &y-z 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I guess now I can just switch some of the values in the matrix according to the desired output, this gives me:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x & y 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1 &\frac{-z}{x} \\ 
 2& \frac{z}{y} &1 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 x+2y&x+z &y-z 
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I'm not sure if this is the right way. Also, I don't understand why I need those basis and am a little confused by the remaining presence of $z$.

I have also tried to check which vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will be generated by the basis, that is:

$$( 1,0 )\to (1,1+z,-z)\quad \quad \quad (0,1)\to (2,z,1-z)$$

And my confusion persists. I'm not sure on how to proceed. Should I try to *write* those vectors in term of $\beta$?

Comment: Seems to me there’s an error in the problem statement. $T$ is not well-defined. As for where to two bases come in the matrix has to operate on vectors with coordinates expressed relative to $\alpha$ and produce vectors with coordinates expressed relative to $\beta$.

Comment: @amd Yes. My professor assumed today that she did a mistake with the $z$, I prefered to assume that I did something stupid and did not pay attention to the lecture. Now I can handle it.